# Last item of RecyclerView remains visible on the layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView inside of a Fragment. I use Data Binding and Navigation Component.
My problem is, when I go back to the previous fragment using the back arrow or just navigate back, and after that I open again the fragment, where I have the RecyclerView, the last item will be still there, but the list is totally empty.

I call this method when I close and open the fragment with the RecyclerView.

```
fun removeAllItems()
{
    listOfItems.clear()
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, listOfItems.lastIndex)
}
```

I have tried notifyDataSetChanged() also, but still I have the same issue.

Any idea why does it happen?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Finally I could solve the problem.
The onCreate() method:

```
private lateinit var listItemAdapter: ListItemAdapter

listItemAdapter = ListItemAdapter(context, mutableListOf<ListItem>())
Log.d(TAG, "Size_4: ${listItemAdapter.itemCount}")
listItemAdapter.removeAllItems()
binding.rvCreateNewListFourthItem.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = listItemAdapter
}
Log.d(TAG, "Size_6: ${listItemAdapter.itemCount}")
```

Results: Size_4: 0
Results: Size_6: 0

After thse lines I have only 2 setOnClickListeners, which opens 2 other dialogs.

```
override fun onResume()
{
    super.onResume()
    Log.d(TAG, "Size_3: ${listItemAdapter.itemCount}")
    listItemAdapter.removeAllItems()
    Log.d(TAG, "Size_5: ${listItemAdapter.itemCount}")
}
```

Results: Size_3: 1
Results: Size_5: 0

The solution was to call the removeAllItems() method on the adapter.
When the fragment reached the onResume() method, the list contained the last item from the last session.

Comment: Most likely, after you return to the previous screen, you again pass a list with one element. Make the list immutable; this will help to identify an error

Comment: share your listOfItems initialisation code!